# How to log only those field which got update during Update API call in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to log only those fields which will be updated during the Update API call. Like if I have 10 columns in my Table but only three got updated in a API call, only those three fields should be logged.

I tried like this but it is not covering all conditions and giving null value sometimes.

Here I'm checking if existing employee value is equals to coming payload's value before calling get and set function for update, but if any of the value will be null it is throwing error.

Tried Code

```
//existingOrgEmployee is DB mysql entry
// and employeeInfo is coming Request from Api Payload
if (employeeInfo.getEmployeeFirstName() != null) { 
               if(!existingOrgEmployee.getFirstName().equals(employeeInfo.getEmployeeFirstName())){
                    log.info("EmployeeFirstName Updated for Orgemployee  : 
                         "+existingOrgEmployee.getOrgEmployeeId());
                }
                existingOrgEmployee.setFirstName(employee Info.getEmployeeFirstName());
            }
```

In payload all the fields will be present but only those which are different or empty in db column will be changed, thats why I have applied if condition before set function

This is the update function within **Service Class**

```
 private void updateExistingEmployee(OrgEmployeeMap existingOrgEmployee, RequestMessage requestMessage) {
        try {
            EmployeeInformation employeeInfo = requestMessage.getData().get(0).getDemographicData().getEmployeeInformation().get(0);

            if (employeeInfo.getEmployeeFirstName() != null) {
               if(!existingOrgEmployee.getFirstName().equals(employeeInfo.getEmployeeFirstName())){
                    log.info("EmployeeFirstName Updated for Orgemployee  : 
                         "+existingOrgEmployee.getOrgEmployeeId());
                }
                existingOrgEmployee.setFirstName(employee Info.getEmployeeFirstName());
            }
            if (employeeInfo.getEmployeeLastName() != null) {

                existingOrgEmployee.setLastName(employeeInfo.getEmployeeLastName());
            }
            if (employeeInfo.getDOB() != null) {

                existingOrgEmployee.setDob(employeeInfo.getDOB());
            }
            if (employeeInfo.getGender() != null) {

                existingOrgEmployee.setGender(employee Info.getGender());
            }
            if (employeeInfo.getEmail() != null) {
                if(!existingOrgEmployee.getEmail().equals(employeeInfo.getEmail())){
                    log.info("Email Updated for Orgemployee  : "+existingOrgEmployee.getEmail());
                }
                existingOrgEmployee.setEmail(employeeInfo.getEmail());
            }

            orgEmployeeMapRepository.save(existingOrgEmployee);

        log.info("Updated Employee : " + existingOrgEmployee);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            log.error("error in processing the request error", e.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("An unexpected error occurred: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
```

Also this is not optimized approach, How can I log updated fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe a bit cleaner but not that perfect, but you could use an object like this :

```
public static class Updater {
  private final OrgEmployeeMap existing;
  private final EmployeeInformation information;
  private final Set<String> updatedFields = new HashSet<>();

  public Updater(OrgEmployeeMap existing, EmployeeInformation information) {
    this.existing = existing;
    this.information = information;
  }

  /**
   * @param fieldName the name of the field that is updated
   * @param newValueGetter a function that retrieves the new value of the field from a {@link EmployeeInformation}
   * @param oldValueGetter a function that retrieves the old value of the field from a {@link OrgEmployeeMap}
   * @param oldValueSetter a consumer that sets the new value of the field to a {@link OrgEmployeeMap}
   * @return this
   * @param <T> the type of the value that is updated
   */
  public <T> Updater update(String fieldName,
                            Function<EmployeeInformation, T> newValueGetter,
                            Function<OrgEmployeeMap, T> oldValueGetter,
                            BiConsumer<OrgEmployeeMap, T> oldValueSetter) {
      //retrieve the new value from the information 
      final var newValue = newValueGetter.apply(information);
      //retrieve the old value from the existing employee 
      final var oldValue = oldValueGetter.apply(existing);
      if (newValue == null || newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
          //no update needed, just return this
          return this;
      }
      //field is modified, add the fieldName to the set of updateFields
      this.updatedFields.add(fieldName);
      //set the new value with the provided setter
      oldValueSetter.accept(existing, newValue);
      return this;
  }

  public Set<String> getUpdatedFields() {
    return updatedFields;
  }
}
```

You can use it in your method like this:

```
private void updateExistingEmployee(OrgEmployeeMap existingOrgEmployee, RequestMessage requestMessage) {
    try {
        EmployeeInformation employeeInfo = requestMessage.getData().get(0).getDemographicData().getEmployeeInformation().get(0);
        final var updater = new Updater(existingOrgEmployee, employeeInfo);

        updater
            .update("FirstName", EmployeeInformation::getEmployeeFirstName, OrgEmployeeMap::getFirstName, OrgEmployeeMap::setFirstName)
            .update("LastName", EmployeeInformation::getEmployeeLastName, OrgEmployeeMap::getLastName, OrgEmployeeMap::setLastName)
            .update("DOB", EmployeeInformation::getDOB, OrgEmployeeMap::getDob, OrgEmployeeMap::setDob)
            .update("Gender", EmployeeInformation::getGender, OrgEmployeeMap::getGender, OrgEmployeeMap::setGender)
            .update("Email", EmployeeInformation::getEmail, OrgEmployeeMap::getEmail, OrgEmployeeMap::setEmail);

        final var modifiedFields = updater.getUpdatedFields();
        if (!modifiedFields.isEmpty()) {
            log.info("Updated employee : " + String.join(", ", modifiedFields));
        }

        orgEmployeeMapRepository.save(existingOrgEmployee);

        log.info("Updated Employee : " + existingOrgEmployee);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        log.error("error in processing the request error", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("An unexpected error occurred: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

**Some explanations:**

To update a field you need to perform the following operations :

1. Get the new value
2. Get the old value
3. If the new value is null or is equal to the old value -> done
4. Update with the new value (and keep track of the name of the updated field)

These steps are always the same regardless of the type of the fields. What depends of the type are the "Get"s, the "Set" actions (there is technically also the "is equal" but since it is a method between values of the type, it is already taken care of).

These "Get" and "Set" actions are provided as parameters ([Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) for the "Get" and [BiConsumer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) for the "Set") of the method `update` that then needs to be a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Comment: Why does it printing for DOB everytime whether I am updating that or not, also can you please give a little brief exactly what is happening in code. It is working for rest of the fields

Comment: Do I need to change <T> or it can be used like this? Actually I'm ot understanding Function<EmployeeInformation, T> newValueGetter, what does this exactly mean? <T> here ?

Comment: I add some documentations and explanation with links to the Java documentation that explains better than me the meaning of the <T> in front of the update method